# How to conditionally create a bean using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, factory, spring-bean

I have this pattern:

```
public class Factory {
    public GenericBean get(ContextEnum context, OneTypeArgs args) {
        switch (context) {
        case OneContext:
            Action a = new OneAction(args);
            return new GenericBean(a);
        case TwoContext:
            Action b = new SecondAction();
            return new GenericBean(b);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I avoid the switch statement and configure Spring to be able to construct itself this kind of objects grape ?

I have two problems and I don't know how to handle them:

1. Action construction depends on a context to be able to find correct implementation.
2. Constructor arguments are dynamic.

Comment: Have you checked [Spring Profile](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/)? I believe it could be handy for your case.

Comment: I don't see the problem with your implementation. Is there a specific reason that your solution doesn't seem right to you?

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo : It's not easy to add/modify profile in my project, we have to follow many politicals processes to do it. I can't add a profile "just to pimp" my factory :)

Comment: @Jeremy : this exemple is very simple as I tried to take the minimum to expose my problem. I have multiple reason : I dislike "switch" statement, I dislike "new" keyword, and I find my solution too monolithic. For exemple, if I want to mock the "OneAction" class for test purpose, I can't. And I want to know a way to be able to use Spring in this case, because I have regurlarly this kind of issue. Sorry for my poor english....

Comment: So all `Action`s implement the same interface or extend the same class? And does `GenericBean` always receive an `Action`, but you always return a `GenericBean` instance?

Comment: @airdump why you can't mock the 'OneAction'? Unit test is not related with Factory.

Comment: @Magnamag : yes and yes :)

Comment: @airdump Are different implementations of `Action` and `GenericBean` singleton beans, i.e. only 1 instance in the whole Spring application context?